# Static Code Analysis Tools in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis, static-code-analysis, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

Good day

Requesting can you please let me know available Static Code Analysis Tools in Visual Studio 2017 and possible best practices etc.

Comment: I would suggest that any decent static analysis tool will work with VS - and some even have plugins to run the analyser from within the tool (although this is not always the best way...).  For *best practice*, I'm biased but would naturally recommend MISRA...

Answer (score 0):

For C#, Visual Studio includes "FXCop". See [Microsoft Docs: Overview of code analysis for .NET in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/code-analysis-for-managed-code-overview).

For C++, Visual Studio includes `/analyze` as well as C++ Core Guidelines checkers. See [Microsoft Docs: Code analysis for C/C++ overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/code-analysis-for-c-cpp-overview).

For third party solutions, there a number of options you can find with a quick Internet search.